# Setting up tomcat with eclipse on first jsp program

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am just following along the spring tutorial (http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html)

I downloaded this version of Eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/galileosr1

I guess tomcat is a separate install?

**Update**
Is Ant ready to go with eclipse, or that is yet another thing I have to get? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/index.html) needs to be installed seperately from Eclipse. Ant shouldn't require any seperate download/installation, but if you are interested in using Maven then I'd suggest installing the [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin.

Comment: "Install" just meaning unpacking the distribution .zip/.tar.gz file, as it's the most reliable way to find the jars needed to launch Tomcat from within Eclipse.  See also http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ

Answer (score 1):

You'll also need the [eclipse tomcat plugin](http://eclipse-plugins.2y.net/eclipse/plugin_details.jsp?id=1).  With Eclipse, chances are whatever you need that it doesn't come by default, there is probably a [plugin](http://eclipse-plugins.2y.net/eclipse/index.jsp) for it already.

Ant should be good to go though.

Comment: If you download the j2ee edition of eclipse you don't need to install anything else (besides unzipping Tomcat itself somewhere).

Comment: Ok I did get teh j2ee edition, but I figured tomcat would be setup automagically!

Comment: There's no J2EE version. There's however a Java EE version.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the JavaEE version of Eclipse, it comes with a lot of tools that are useful for  web development. You can also add server adapters quite easily (and even install Tomcat when adding servers). Here is a quick [WTP Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html) that goes through installing Tomcat. In my opinion, WTP is a must have for Java EE developers using Eclipse!

Eclipse already comes with Ant built in.

Cheers,
Shane